# Scrape 1 More Field From Webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code goes into a webpage, and takes certain data from each row

I however want to also get the "topics" from each row. For example listed as "Presidential Session and Community Psychiatry" in row 1, above the "Speakers" text.

My code is currently able to scrape Titles and Chairs of each row (denoted as Role and Name) but not the topic?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://s7.goeshow.com/apa/annual/2021/session_search.cfm?_ga=2.259773066.1015449088.1617295032-97934194.1617037074')
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.select('#datatable')
for table in tables:
    for title in table.select('tr td.title'):
        print(title.text.strip())
        title_row = title.parent
        speaker_row = title_row.next_sibling
        for speaker in speaker_row.select('span.session-speaker'):
            role = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-role').text.strip()
            name = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-name').text.strip()
            topic=speaker.select_one('span.session-track-label').text.strip() 
            print(role, name,topic)

        print()
```

Comment: You went too deep into the tr for each row and aren't pulling outside the session speaker. The span.session-speaker is the following sibling for the tds that house the elements you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tables = soup.select('#datatable')
for table in tables:
    for title in table.select('tr td.title'):
        print(title.text.strip())
        title_row = title.parent
        speaker_row = title_row.next_sibling
        for topic in speaker_row.select('span.session-track-label'):
            print(topic.text.strip())
        for speaker in speaker_row.select('span.session-speaker'):
            role = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-role').text.strip()
            name = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-name').text.strip()
            
            print(role, name)
```

If you want all the topics prior to the names and roles you have to target them from the row and not the following sibling.

Answer (score 1):

I think this row contain only 'role' and 'name'.

It means 'span.session-speaker' contains only 'span.session-speaker-role' and 'span.session-speaker-name'.

```
for speaker in speaker_row.select('span.session-speaker'):
```

You can try below code.

```
L_topics=[]
for speaker in speaker_row.select('td.session-divider-line') :
    role = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-role').text.strip()
    name = speaker.select_one('span.session-speaker-name').text.strip()
    for topics in speaker_row.select('span.session-track-label'):
        L_topics.append(topics.text.strip())
    print(role,name,L_topics[0],L_topics[1])
```